# Angular6 HttpClient error handling within map

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, httpclient

I am using the angular6 HTTPClient in my service and would like to maintain the next and err paths of the Observable to the subscriber.

e.g. My component looks something like this:

```
private myFun(query: string) {

    this.myService.login(data).subscribe(next => {

        // Do successful stuff
        console.log('Got the data: ' + next);
    },
    err => {
       // Handle all errors here
       console.error('good luck next time')
    });
}
```

My service is using a pipe along with the map and catchError.

```
private findData(in: string): Observable<string> {

    return this.http.post<string>(self.url, '')
        .pipe(
            map( response => {
            //Check the data is valid
            if (this.dataValid(response)){
                     return this.convertedData(response);
            } else {
                throw new Error('failed parsing data');
            }
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
  }
```

I can detect the parsing issue and raise the error via catchError but what I am struggling to understand is how to process the catchError.

The error handler looks like this:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        // Client Side Error
        console.error('Client side error:', error.error.message);
    } else if (error.message === 'failed parsing data') {
        // Client Side Processing Error
        console.error(error.message);
        return throwError(error.message);
    } else {
        // Service Side Error
        console.error(`Server returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }

    // return an observable error message
    return throwError('failed to contact server');
}
```

It does the job but I can't help thinking there must be a better, more Angular/RxJS way, of doing this.

What I would have expected is to have hit the 'error.error instanceof ErrorEvent' path of the error handler. I don't understand how the "error: HttpErrorResponse" parameter is being updated - I am just throwing a "new Error('failed parsing data');".

Any advice/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, it is evident that `catchError` callback can take either `HttpErrorResponse` or `Error` type. So `catchError` callback input should be either type as `any` or `Error | HttpErrorResponse` like this -

```
private handleError(error: any // or it can be Error | HttpErrorResponse) {

    //now do console.log(error) and see what it logs
    //as per the output adjust your code

    if (error instanceof Error) {
        // Client Side Error
        console.error('Client side error:', error.error.message);
    } else if (error.message === 'failed parsing data') {
        // Client Side Processing Error
        console.error(error.message);
        return throwError(error.message);
    } else {
        // Service Side Error
        console.error(`Server returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }

    // return an observable error message
    return throwError('failed to contact server');
}
```